# Confusion in String Manipulation

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, mathematica-8

`InputForm[{a, b, c, d, e, f}]`  gives  `{a, b, c, d, e, f}`

`InputForm[Characters["SOMETHING"]]`   gives   `{"S", "O", "M", "E", "T", "H", "I", "N", "G"}`

But why does not `Drop[InputForm[Characters["SOMETHING"]],1]` give `{"O", "M", "E", "T", "H", "I", "N", "G"}`

but gives a  InputForm[] and nothing else?

How can I achieve this?

Thank You

Comment: I'm not familiar with the language so can't answer but as a general rule, you should mention what you're getting as well as what you want to get (be that different output or an error)

Comment: You are starting at index 1 instead of 0? (index 0 is the 'S')

Comment: @f01 Mathematica uses 1-based indexing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you evaluate

```
InputForm[Characters["SOMETHING"]]
```

Mathematica internally produces the result

```
InputForm[List["S","O","M","E","T","H","I","N","G"]]
```

i.e. it's an expression with `InputForm` as a head, which contains `ListList["S","O","M","E","T","H","I","N","G"]` as its first subexpression. You don't see the `InputForm` head when Mathematica displays the expression, because the front end only uses it as a hint as to how the expression should be shown, but it's still there behind the scenes.

Then when you use `Drop[..., 1]`, it looks at the expression it's given, picks out the first subexpression, which is `List["S","O","M","E","T","H","I","N","G"]`, and discards it. That leaves just `InputForm[]`.

To make an analogy: if you evaluated

```
Drop[List[List["S","O","M","E","T","H","I","N","G"]], 1]
```

you would understand why you'd get an empty list back, right? It's the same thing going on.

Comment: @user1709828 the simplest solution is to avoid using `InputForm` except for wrapping something for display. If you want all your output, or something in particular, to always show in `InputForm` there are several ways to handle that

Comment: @ Rojo, I want to use the output of 

each remaining elements of Drop[InputForm[Characters["SOMETHING"]],1] and use in ToCharacterCode, which requires input in " " form. and I am trying to achieve it through InputForm.

Comment: @user1709828 still, not a good reason to use `InputForm`. To convert back to a string you want `StringJoin`, or for this particular case you could just apply `ToCharacterCode` directly to the string and then use `Drop` on the result of that (because `ToCharacterCode` gives a list).